# udev rules once a device is added in linux does not work

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev, hotplugging

Here is a simple rule I created in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules:

```
ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",    
ATTRS{serial}=="NA453QQS", SUBSYS\
TEM=="usb", RUN+="~/1/linux/MyCode/Code/run.sh"
```

The run.sh is pretty simple and uses insmod and rmmod to insert and remove a module from kernel.

Now my external drive is added and remove but the run.sh fails to run. What is the problem here?

I have looked at [documentation](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.hotplug.html) as well as this question [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184724). I am using a Debian machine.

Comment: Try using a fully-qualified path to run.sh

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the tilde since your HOME directory is not set. Use an absolute PATH for the run.sh program

Comment: More than that, this won't be run under the user's account anyway.